# What Server dns template I need to make to meet denic requirements

Tags: domain-name-system, configuration

I have problem with denic dns propagation at some .de domains. 
I have on my configuration dns server this template:

`<domain>.  NS  ns1.itplace.ro.
    <domain>.   NS  ns2.itplace.ro.
    <domain>.   A   <ip>
    <domain>.   AAAA    <ipv6>
    <domain>.   MX (10) mail.<domain>.
    <domain>.   TXT v=spf1 +a +mx -all
    <ip> / 24   PTR <domain>.
    ftp.<domain>.   CNAME   <domain>.
    imap.<domain>.  A   <ip>
    mail.<domain>.  A   <ip>
    ns1.<domain>.   A   <ip>
    ns2.<domain>.   A   213.251.188.141
    pop.<domain>.   A   <ip>
    pop3.<domain>.  A   <ip>
    smtp.<domain>.  A   <ip>
    webmail.<domain>.   A   <ip>`

At SOA dns record I have:

`TTL: 3600 sec
Refresh: 7200 sec
Retry: 2400 sec
Expire: 1209600 sec
Minimum: 43200 hours`

At http://www.denic.de/hintergrund/nast.html I got this errors:

`Warning | 102  | Provided glue records not applicable (NS) cyberstudio.de IN NS ns1.domainserver.com /37.187.74.132 /2001:41d0:a:2a84:0:0:0:1
Warning | 102   | Provided glue records not applicable (NS) cyberstudio.de IN NS ns2.domainserver.com /213.251.188.141 /2001:41d0:a:2a84:0:0:0:1
Error | 901 | Unexpected RCODE (target, entity, RCODE) /213.251.188.141:53 cyberstudio.de
SERVFAIL`

Can someone to explain what I do wrong here, because I have some good websites which are offline now?

Comment: If you put the real values in here instead of trying to mask them this would likely be a quick problem to solve. DNS is quite difficult to troubleshoot if you can't reproduce the problem and look at the responses. Plus if your problem is a typo, we can't possibly see that.

Comment: I just edit this content to be more accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Your NS records given here do not match your glue records given to your domain registrar:

```
Nserver: docks02.rzone.de
Nserver: shades02.rzone.de
```

Contact your domain registrar to change these records to the values you wish.

Comment: Michael, I can't change the nameservers until the Server settings meet the standard configuration requested by denic. Each time the domain registrar give me an error for my ns, due to itplace server settings and requested by denic.